# Kohana Framework: way to load config using absolute file path

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

How to load config from a specific folder, for example:

 `DOCROOT."assets/config/pre-load.php"` 

Defaults method will search in 

`(APPPATH|MODPATH|SYSPATH)."/config/".DOCROOT."assets/config/pre-load"`,

but I need to go out from `(APPPATH|MODPATH|SYSPATH)."/config/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour is to search in priority into `'APPPATH.'config/'` , and can be customized in your `application/bootstrap.php` file. The default bootstrap file is well commented.

```
/**
 * Attach a file reader to config. Multiple readers are supported.
 */
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_File);
```

You can add before (or after, depending of what you want) a new config file directory (relative to all `Kohana::$_paths` you can also redefine, default being  `array(APPPATH, SYSPATH)`.

For example,

```
/**
 * Attach a file reader to config. Multiple readers are supported.
 */
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_File);
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_File('../assets/config'));
```

if you want to add it later in the code (let's say in your controller initialisation) just add the line where you want. If the config file should be used only when all other config is missing, use FALSE for the 2nd parameter of the attach method (you can see comments inside php files of `system/classes/Kohana/Config.php` or `system/classes/Kohana/Config/File/Reader.php` ).